# Probability of random selection of sweets

Tags: probability

There is a bag of $10$ sweets with $5$ red, $3$ green and $2$ yellow.
Dan chooses one at random and then keeps it, and then Carl chooses one.

What is the probability that Carl chooses a yellow sweet.

I don't know how to do this?

Comment: Do you know about "conditional" probabilities?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), or if you don't know anything about it, then simply sum up the probabilities of the following **disjoint events**:

- The probability that Dan chooses red and Carl chooses yellow is $\frac{5}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{9}=\frac{10}{90}$
- The probability that Dan chooses green and Carl chooses yellow is $\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{9}=\frac{6}{90}$
- The probability that Dan chooses yellow and Carl chooses yellow is $\frac{2}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{9}=\frac{2}{90}$

So the probability that Carl chooses yellow is $\frac{10}{90}+\frac{6}{90}+\frac{2}{90}=\frac{18}{90}=\frac{1}{5}=20\%$.

Answer (score 3):

What's the probability that Carl chooses a yellow sweet given that Dan chose a sweet that isn't yellow?

What's the probability that Carl chooses a yellow sweet given that Dan chose a sweet that IS yellow?

That should be enough to help you do your homework.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: When Dan chooses a yellow sweet, the probability of Carl choosing one is $1/9$.

If Dan picks anything else, at that point, the probability of Carl choosing yellow is $2/9$.

Answer (score 2):

Either Dan chooses a yellow sweet or he doesn't, so we'll see what happens in each case.

If Dan chooses a yellow sweet, this is with probability $\frac{2}{10}$. So there are nine sweets left, one of which is yellow. What is the probability that Carl will choose a yellow sweet here? Multiply the two probabilities.

Now, if Dan chooses a non-yellow sweet, this is with probability $\frac{8}{10}$. So there are nine sweets left, two of which are yellow. What is the probability that Carl will choose a yellow sweet here? Multiply the two probabilities.

Now, you should have two numbers. Add them together.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is $\frac2 {10}$. We know this because it doesnt matter what Dan chooses, he has an equal probability of eliminating anything, weighted based on their respective frequencies, i.e.
\begin{align*}
P(r)&=.5\\
P(g)&=.3\\
P(y)&=.2\\
\end{align*}
so his choice does not effect the probability of anything more than anything else.

Comment: Dan has an equal probability to eliminate red ($5$ out of $10$) and green ($3$ out of $10$)?

Comment: Sorry about the imprecise statement of the reason, I am not sure how to state this in a clearer way, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Put invisible distinct labels on the sweets. Any individual  sweet is just as likely to be chosen first as to be chosen second.

Answer (score 1):

If Dan chooses a yellow one, then Carl has less chance, the chance of that, since $2$ of $10$ are yellow is $2/10=0,2$.

Now, if Carl chooses, in the first case, he needs to pick that $1$ yellow from the $9$ sweets, the chance of that is $1/9=0,111...$

In all other cases, Dan chooses something else, chance for that is $1-0,2=0,8$.

In the second case, he needs to pick $1$ from the $9$, but $2$ of them are yellow, so his chance is $2/9$.

If we sum these cases:: $0,2*0,111... + 0,8*0,222...$ Multiplying this with $100$ gives you the the answer in %